# Literature and Intro to Dispersion Trading

Tags: options, trading, correlation, dispersion

I am familiar with the basic idea of the dispersion trade i.e. index vol vs constituent vol and implied correlation. I am wondering if there are any standard resources (pdfs, books, presentations) that discuss the concept more in depth. Is there any standard literature in the area?

Comment: For reference I have found these: https://www.nuclearphynance.com/User%20Files/2/Dispersion%20-%20A%20guide%20for%20the%20clueless%201.1.pdf and https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/avellane/Lecture10Quant.pdf

Comment: I don't know anything about it but if you go here, there are a lot of other related things. if you saw them already, then my bad for noise. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C33&q=dispersion+trading&btnG=